# Efficiently unpack a list of varying length dataframes

Tags: r, list, unpack

I have a list comprising a large number of time series dataframes covering varying years. I am using `lapply` to successfully unpack the list but I want something quicker. One complication is that some dataframes are empty but I want to keep a record of them so that after the unpacking I can `cbind` the correct labels with the data.

I am timing my current attempt with example data using microbenchmark.

```
library("plyr")
library("microbenchmark")

# Create some example dataframes of varying length.
ts1 <- data.frame(year=2004:2019, value=14:29)
ts2 <- data.frame(year=2006:2018, value=18:6)
ts3 <- NULL
ts4 <- data.frame(year=2005:2017, value=25:37)
ts5 <- NULL

# Combine the example dataframes into a list.
ts_data <- list(ts1, ts2, ts3, ts4, ts5)

# Function to unpack time series data if not empty and return a dataframe.
fn_unpack_ts <- function(ts) {
  if (!plyr::empty(ts)) {  
    df <- t(ts$value)
    colnames(df) <- ts$year
  } else {
    df <- NA
  }
  return(as.data.frame(df))
}

# Use lapply to run through each dataframe.
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
l_ts <- Reduce(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(ts_data, fn_unpack_ts)), times=100
)

# Tidy up the final dataframe.
l_ts$df <- NULL
```

The required output dataframe looks like this:

```
> l_ts
   2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
 1   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
 2   NA   NA   18   17   16   15   14   13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6   NA
 3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
 4   NA   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   NA   NA
 5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

And my own personal timings for 100 repetitions in milliseconds is:

```
           min       lq     mean   median       uq     max neval
l_ts  2.844698 3.024238 3.283312 3.093525 3.357831 9.21223   100
```

I would like to know if there is a more efficient approach to unpacking my example data. I suspect it would entail not returning a dataframe each time but it is the only way I could get it to work when using `rbind.fill` to handle the varying numbers of years.

**UPDATE**

Very good solutions proposed by #A. Suliman and #Uwe. My testing with real data comprising 1,098 rows and 10 repetitions reveals:

```
expr                                                               mean (ms)     
Reduce(rbind.fill, lapply(ts_data, fn_unpack_ts))                  1326.2   
purrr::map_dfr(ts_data, fn_unpack_ts)                               133.7 
dcast(rbindlist(ts_data, idcol="id")[CJ(id=seq_along(ts_data),
  year, unique=TRUE), on=.(id, year)], id~year)                      15.0
```

... so I declare the `rbindlist` approach the winner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach which uses `rbindlist()` to combine the dataframes, a cross join `CJ()` to complete the ids of missing time sequences, and `dcast()` to reshape from long to wide format:

```
library(data.table)
dcast(rbindlist(ts_data, idcol = "id")[CJ(id = seq_along(ts_data), year, unique = TRUE), on = .(id, year)], id ~ year)
```

> ```
>    id 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014 2015 2016 2017 2018 2019
> 1:  1   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29
> 2:  2   NA   NA   18   17   16   15   14   13   12   11   10    9    8    7    6   NA
> 3:  3   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> 4:  4   NA   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32   33   34   35   36   37   NA   NA
> 5:  5   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
> ```

I have *not* included benchmark timings for the given very small sample dataset as this would only measure the overhead of function calls. A meaningful benchmark would require to study the timings for *all* solutions on *one* computer at varying (small and large) problem sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one option using `purrr::map_dfr`

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  l_ts <- purrr::map_dfr(ts_data, fn_unpack_ts), unit = "ms",times=100
)

Unit: milliseconds
                                  expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
l_ts <- map_dfr(ts_data, fn_unpack_ts) 0.367476 0.3829495 0.4368147 0.3925645 0.417654 1.181447   100
```